# Imports vs. Class Hierarchy in Java

Tags: java

Hi I am a beginner in Java.
I just read about Class Hierarchy-

`java.lang.Object
   java.awt.Component
       java.awt.Container
           javax.swing.JComponent`

Also, class object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass.

If Object class is the superclass then why we import every class seperately in Java ?
Wouldn't be it sufficient to import just java.lang.Object ?

Comment: no, because that would only let you use object, and not things that extend object

Comment: You don't have to import every class separately - everything in the java.lang package is available without importing it.

Comment: Even though this is a very basic question, I don't believe it deserves the -2. It seems to me the OP is thinking critically about what they're learning, and making an attempt to understand the logic behind this concept. I can see why the OP would have that question. Having said that, I do believe it is a perfect question to ask one's professor instead.

Comment: @PaulRichter I agree. This is a basic question but it's also specific enough to be suitable for StackOverflow, not "too broad" as some have suggested when voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that every class in Java is a descendant of the Object class, but if you just imported Object, that's all you would get. You wouldn't get ArrayList, HashSet, etc. or any other class that's defined in the API.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for multi-level, single root hierarchy is --> while doing garbage collection, everything is treated as an object, so they are handled in a common way. The same applies when inserting / removing on some collections or synchronizing on threads. 
Object has just the *basic* methods and fields like `wait()`, `notify()`, `hashCode()`. Other classes, though they implicitly extend Object, provide their own set of methods and  properties. So, you have to import them.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `import` declarations only affect the way that names are resolved. They don't affect what classes you can use, and they are not affected by inheritance.

Most people find it convenient to use *simple names* from the class library. To do this, you need to add `import` declarations. The exception is with names from the `java.lang` package, which is implicitly imported into every Java program.

For example, if you wanted to write your own Swing component, you could do this without using any imports:

```
class MyComponent extends javax.swing.JComponent { ... }
```

Using *fully qualified* names this way is cumbersome, so most people prefer imports:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;

class MyComponent extends JComponent { ... }
```

It's true that `JComponent` is a subclass of `java.awt.Container` and `java.awt.Component`. It's not necessary to import anything from `java.awt` in order to use Swing's `JComponent`. If you do, you can always use the fully qualified package name. But as above, most people find it convenient to import names from these packages so that they can just write `Container` instead of `java.awt.Container` everywhere.